# Pygame rectangular collision

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have a bug with my collision code and I can't seem to find the problem. When my character is colliding with top block face, the algorithm detects that I'm also colliding with left side.

So in effect, I can't move right and sometimes left because of faulty collision detection.

```
def BlockCollision(self, vector):

    pos           = self.GetPos()
    predicted_pos = Vector.Add(pos, self.GetVelocity())

    top           = predicted_pos[1] - (self.Entity.h / 2)
    bottom        = predicted_pos[1] + (self.Entity.h / 2)
    left          = predicted_pos[0] - (self.Entity.w/2)
    right         = predicted_pos[0] + (self.Entity.w/2)


    collision_direction = "NaN"

    for k, v in enumerate(ents.FindByClass("block")):

        ent     = ents.FindByClass("block")[k]
        ent_pos = ent.GetPos()

        block_top, block_bottom = ent_pos[1] - (1/2 * ent.Entity.h),  ent_pos[1] + (1/2 * ent.Entity.h)
        block_left, block_right = ent_pos[0] - (1/2 * ent.Entity.w),  ent_pos[0] + (1/2 * ent.Entity.w)

        colliding_left_noz, colliding_right_noz = (predicted_pos[0] < ent_pos[0] and (right > block_left and right < block_right)), ( not(predicted_pos[0] < ent_pos[0]) and (left > block_left and left < block_right))
        colliding_left, colliding_right = colliding_left_noz and (bottom > block_top and bottom < block_bottom) or (top > block_top and top < block_bottom), colliding_right_noz and (bottom > block_top and bottom < block_bottom) or (top > block_top and top < block_bottom)

        colliding_top_nox, colliding_bottom_nox = (predicted_pos[1] < ent_pos[1]) and (bottom > block_top and bottom < block_bottom), not(predicted_pos[1] < ent_pos[1]) and (top > block_top and top < block_bottom)
        colliding_top, colliding_bottom = colliding_top_nox and ((right > block_left and right < block_right) or (left > block_left and left < block_right)), colliding_bottom_nox and ((right > block_left and right < block_right) or (left > block_left and left < block_right))



        if colliding_left:

            if self.Velocity[0] > 0:
                self.Velocity = [0, self.Velocity[1]]
            else:
                pass
        elif colliding_right:

            if self.Velocity[0] < 0:
                self.Velocity = [0, self.Velocity[1]]
            else:
                pass
        if colliding_top:

            if self.Velocity[1] > 0:
                self.Velocity = [self.Velocity[0], 0]
            else:
                pass
        elif colliding_bottom:

            if self.Velocity[1] < 0:
                self.Velocity =[self.Velocity[0], 0]
            else:
                pass
```

So does anyone know what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

When calculating `colliding_left` and `colliding_right`, you forgot the parentheses around the 2nd and 3rd clauses. You did the `colliding_top` and `colliding_bottom` correctly.